# Qt: Refreshing Image

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build a self-refreshing Image in Qt that loads a JPEG from disk cyclically with a frequency of i.e. 5Hz.

My idea was to simply use a QLabel and show the Picture, but this tends to use quite some CPU load:

```
m_picture_label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(m_filename).scaledToWidth(size().width())));
```

I then tried to use OpenGL, but this version uses more than 90% of my embedded PC, so this isn't an option.

Is there any chance to reduce the load?

Regards,
VanDahlen

Comment: Why do you want to refresh in such short intervall? Maybe you can use the`QFileSystemWatcher` class to detect modifications of the file and reload it only if a modification was done

Comment: It is ought to be a simple webcam. The images are provided as JPEG files.

Comment: Use the webcam with Qt directly, bypass the file system altogether.

Comment: No, I need the Images on disk, besides Qt. Furthermore it is an MJPEG Stream.

Comment: You could also try to draw the image with a QPainter instead of using a QLabel to display the image.

Comment: painting in openGL would be the fastest option for sure. On the other hand, when reading every frame from the filesystem, painting might not be the bottleneck to deal with.

Comment: @VanDahlen - I will once again suggest you use the webcam with Qt directly. If you need to write the images on the file system, do it in Qt. This way you will eliminate the overhead of having to read the image from the fs.